# Update SQLite db & use updated records in same async fuction

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, async-await

I'm using this method to update a tuple of a particular table

```
public async void Update(MyTable entity)
{
    SQLiteAsyncConnection conn = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(path);
    await conn.UpdateAsync(entity); 
}
```

Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn263243.aspx

Now in main, i'm trying to update a record in MyTable & I'm binding MyTable records to a ViewModel which is bound to the view.

```
private async void button_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MyTableRepository.Update(scheduleRecord);

    this.DefaultViewModel["MyViewModel"] =await ViewModelClass.GetMyTableDataAsync();
}
```

The problem here is that the view is not getting updated. After I stop the application & check db values, the db seems to be updated & after that if i run the app again, the required updated view is displayed.

I'm new to async-await. So my feeling is that maybe ViewModel is updated even before

```
MyTableRepository.Update(scheduleRecord);
```

is executed.
I actually dont know the exact cause. Please Help.

Comment: I just wanted to share that module `(09) Local data` discusses SQLite in detail for any developer finding this article and wanting to learn a little more. http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2014/10/ready-to-learn-developing-universal.html

Comment: Thanx @JerryNixon-MSFT. There's quite a lot of stuff to learn on the link provied. By the way I'm very sorry. The bug was in how I update MyViewModel. Actually I should have removed scheduleRecord from MyViewModel & then i should called this.DefaultViewModel["MyViewModel"] =await ViewModelClass.GetMyTableDataAsync(); So in short, my logic got wrong. Anyways a million thanx 4 ur help

Answer (score 2):

Your `Update` method is running in a "fire and forget" fasion. When you `await GetMyTableDataAsync()`, the data may not yet be updated in your database.

What you need to do is change `Update` from `async void` to `async Task`:

```
public async Task UpdateAsync(MyTable entity)
```

and `await` on it:

```
await UpdateAsync(entity);
```

Your full code would look like this:

```
private async void button_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    await MyTableRepository.UpdateAsync(scheduleRecord);

    this.DefaultViewModel["MyViewModel"] = await ViewModelClass.GetMyTableDataAsync();
}
```

As a side note:

1. If you're not doing anything other then awaiting inside `UpdateAsync`, you can simply return the executing `Task` and `await` it higher up the call chain:

   ```
   public Task UpdateAsync(MyTable entity)
   {
      SQLiteAsyncConnection conn = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(path);
      return conn.UpdateAsync(entity); 
   }
   ```
2. Make sure you're properly disposing your DB connections.

Comment: I changed the UpdateAsync to async task. Still the same issue... I think your 2nd point is correct, i.e. the DB connections are not disposed properly... figuring out the same at present...

Comment: Unless `SQLiteAsyncConnection.UpdateAsync` is synchronous masquerading as asynchronous, there's no guarantee, in your code, that the data will be saved before it's read.

Comment: @PauloMorgado Please explain. If he uses `await UpdateAsync`, why is there no guarantee for the update before read?

Comment: Your as in question original code, not in your answer code. The OP seemed to be in doubt that you were point out a real problem here.

Comment: I'm very sorry. The bug was in how I update MyViewModel. Actually I should have removed scheduleRecord from MyViewModel & then i should called this.DefaultViewModel["MyViewModel"] =await ViewModelClass.GetMyTableDataAsync(); So in short, my logic got wrong. Anyways a million thanx 4 ur help.